# Problems with UPDATE in CRUD

Tags: php, mysql, crud

I'm newbie in php and i make a simple CRUD app. Unfortunately, I'm stacked with this problem, I don't know what's wrong with my code in my update.php. When i click update in my index.php it Undefined variable. I  think my value in form is wrong. Any help is appreciated.
update.php

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

if (isset($_POST['customerNumber'])) {
    $customerNumber = $_POST['customerNumber'];

    $q  = "SELECT customerNumber, checkNumber, paymentDate, amount FROM payments WHERE customerNumber='$customerNumber'";
    $rq = mysqli_query($conn, $q);

    while ($row = mysqli_feth_assoc($rq)) {
    $customerNumber = $row['customerNumber'];
    $checkNumber    = $row['checkNumber'];
    $paymentDate    = $row['paymentDate'];
    $amount         = $row['amount'];
    }
}
?>
    <!-- from the index.php update -->
<form action="update.php?customerNumber=$customerNumber" method="post">
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="customerNumber" value="<?php echo $row['customerNumber']; ?>" placeholder="Customer Number" required>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="checkNumber" value="<?php echo $row['checkNumber']; ?>"  placeholder="Check Number" required>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="text" name="paymentDate" value="<?php echo $row['paymentDate']; ?>" placeholder="Payment Date" required>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="number" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['amount']; ?>"  placeholder="Amount">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update">
</form>
<?php
    include('connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $customerNumber = $_POST['customerNumber'];
    $checkNumber    = $_POST['checkNumber'];
    $paymentDate    = $_POST['paymentDate'];
    $amount         = $_POST['amount'];

    $q = "UPDATE payments SET customerNumber='$customerNumber', checkNumber='$checkNumber', paymentDate='$paymentDate', amount='$amount' WHERE customerNumber='$customerNumber' ";

    $rq = mysqli_query($conn, $q);

    if($rq){
        header('Location: index.php');
    }else{
        echo "Something went wrong";
    }
}
    ?>
```

Comment: Your form action contains `delete.php?customerNumber=$customerNumber` which is including php variable `$customerNumber` without using php tags, should be `delete.php?customerNumber=<?php echo $customerNumber; ?>`.

Comment: [Insecure Direct Object Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007-Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference)

Comment: Spelling error/typo - **mysqli_feth_assoc**